# www vs non-www ssl certificate?

Tags: security-certificate, no-www

We have a Drupal 6 shopping cart system that works fine on Apache/cPanel. We had an SSL cert for www.xyz.com through NS which expired 2 days ago. My boss called Network Solutions and they walked through the process, uploading a CSR, etc. and purchased a new cert.

But when we tried to -install- the new cert via cPanel it said 'Private Key does not match'.

I -think- what happened is that the domain we selected was the non-www version but the CSR was for the www version.

NS will allow us to upload a new CSR -but- they won't allow us to change the domain from xyz.com to www.xyz.com and they will not issue a refund. SO...

1. If I install the new SSL cert for the non-www domain, can I make this work by editing .htaccess?
2. Or should I just eat the $249 and purchase a -new- cert for www.xyz.com?

I'm paranoid because I don't see any option for 'wild-card' in the NS setup and I don't know enough about Drupal to know if this will matter.

TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters on StackExchange. This is a good question and a bit of a sticky situation. One up-vote on the way! I will let someone who knows best answer the question. I am sure there is a good solution for you.

Comment: Add the output of http://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html for your certificate to the question. This will show the CN / SAN for the certificate you received. Did you change the private key on the server when changing the certificate?

Comment: Sounds like this is the job of your hosting company unless your using a server non-managed. Also unless you have a wildcard SSL cert then yes you need to purchase a new SSL cert. SSL Certifications can support wild card but this is something you normally pay extra for and normally unless you clicked the wild card then your have one that supports one domain with or without a subdomain (one with or without www. - not both.)

Comment: We're using a non-managed host. This may be a moron question, but can't be as simple as using the non-www ssl cert and adding a 301 redirect in .htaccess to redirect www.xyz.com to xyz.com?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting www to non-www is a pretty big change just to get an SSL cert working. Most CAs automatically issue certificates for both versions of a domain so I'm surprised they won't revoke that and re-issue it. Try contacting them again and keep insisting that they "revoke" the issued certificate and re-issue it with the www version of the domain. You haven't been using the certificate and being just a few days in they should be able to work with you on such a simple issue, especially considering they were walking you through the process when it went wrong.

That being said, since most certificates are issues to accommodate for that already I'm tempted to think that the issue lies with the installation; you'd be more likely to get a browser error than a cPanel error otherwise. The domain in the certificate will match the domain in the CSR and the CSR will match the private key; if the certificate doesn't match the private key then you might be trying to attach the new certificate to the old private key.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote. This is a weird situation... I have performed this sort of task many times and never had this problem. I ended up purchasing a new cert from another vendor and it installed with 0 problems. NS -refused- to 'revoke' the cert or refund the money. They offered to re-issue under the non-www domain and that too failed to install. I couldn't have screwed up 2x. Basically, their attitude was: whatever went wrong, you clicked the 'Agree To Terms' fine print and it's on -you-. Given the choice I will NEVER do business with them again. Sorry for venting.

Comment: Hopefully this is not off-topic but I am also wondering whether or not there might be a bug in our hosting company's cPanel and I have unjustly blamed NS (although I don't appreciate their attitude.) I say this because there have been several incidents on this site where the cPanel functions did not work as advertised and tech support had to repair 'under the hood'. I wonder if it is possible to determine this?